# R package installation error: 'packfor'

Tags: r, dll, installation, sourceforge

I'm having trouble installing sourceforge package 'packfor'. It was installed once successfully, then uninstalled, and upon reinstallation...

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/packfor_0.0-8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

This error appears:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/packfor/libs/packfor.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/packfor/libs/packfor.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/packfor’
```

Any ideas? If I force installation, packfor.so does exist in that directory.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Got no errors and was able to load that package after: `install.packages("packfor", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")` running R 3.1.0 in OSX 10.7.5 with the SnowLeopard build. I am unable to understand the statement that you were able to "force" installation.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I'm running R 3.1.1 in OSX 10.9.2 Mavericks. Earlier I found a way to continue with source installation despite errors. After 'forced' installation, the above error message would still appear with library("packfor")

A month later I'm still stuck. It looks like although gcc is installed, the wrong gcc is referenced in the path. Could this be cause of the problem?

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'

If so, how can I stipulate the correct fortran path? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I said I did not understand "forcing". Repeating the verb does NOT clarify. You now need to clarify and you need to specify what your Fortran compiler setup might be. (IIRC they removed the Fortran compiler from the Mavericks toolchain.) If you do not post your full setup and the specific code used its unlikely anyone can help. Perhaps posting on R-SIG-Mac?

Comment: Please see my related follow-up post: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043356/do-multiple-gcc-versions-confuse-dylibs-libgcc-s-1-dylib-and-prevent-binaries). By forcing, I meant that I found a way to complete package installation that disregarded errors. I repeated myself because I don't remember exactly how I accomplished this. It seems to be irrelevant though, as my other post suggests a more systemic problem with gcc. Don't you think? Please specify what other info you need about my fortran setup. I am biologist, not a computer scientist. Thanks.